# html5 history api to work on all links, even inside content div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anyone help me to fix this, its work well on links on menu, before the `div` "content", but when try to navigate the pages, in links inside `div` called "Content", its does work?

This is to load pages without reload header.

```
$(function(){
    $("a[rel='tab']").click(function(e){
        //e.preventDefault(); 
        /*  
        if uncomment the above line, html5 nonsupported browers won't change the url but will display the ajax content;
        if commented, html5 nonsupported browers will reload the page to the specified link. 
        */

        //get the link location that was clicked
        pageurl = $(this).attr('href');

        //to get the ajax content and display in div with id 'content'
        $.ajax({url:pageurl+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
            $('#content').html(data);
        }});

        //to change the browser URL to 'pageurl'
        if(pageurl!=window.location){
            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);    
        }
        return false;  
    });
});

/* the below code is to override back button to get the ajax content without reload*/
$(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    $.ajax({url:location.pathname+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
    }});
});
```

Comment: Try to use $("a[rel='tab']").on('click', function(e){ if you are loading the new links with ajax

Answer (score 0):

You should handle new anchors that are loaded with ajax

```
$(function(){
    $("a[rel='tab']").click(clickhandler);
});
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
    $.ajax({url:location.pathname+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
        $("#content a[rel='tab']").click(clickhandler);
    }});
});

var clickhandler = function(e){
    pageurl = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({url:pageurl+'?rel=tab',success: function(data){
        $('#content').html(data);
        $("#content a[rel='tab']").click(clickhandler);
    }});

    if(pageurl!=window.location){
        window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);    
    }
    return false;  
};
```